# Synchronized methods and static variable access JAVA / ANDROID

Tags: java, android, methods, static, synchronized

I need help with some JAVA theory...

So I recently discovered that if an app uses multiple threads, and there is any possibility of different threads accessing the same shared variable at the same time, then one should use "synchronized" methods to get/set said variable.

So... in my (location aware) app, I have variables LAT, and LON that belong to the MainActivity and are static.  They are accessed from background services like so:

```
appendToPOST(MainActivity.LAT);
```

And in MainActivity itself, I am using google play location services, and so in the onLocationChanged() callback method in MainActivity, I have:

```
LAT = [arbitrary Double value goes here];
```

So therefore, that means I should implement:

```
public static synchronized void setLAT(Double inLAT){

    LAT = inLAT;

}

public static synchronized void setLON(Double inLON){

    LON = inLON;

}

public static synchronized Double getLAT(){

    return LAT;

}

public static synchronized Double getLON(){

    return LON;

}
```

Correct?  Thanks for any clarification/help.

Added: Also, should I change the code in the onLocationChanged() method to use the synchronized methods, even though it exists in the same class as the variable?

Comment: in basic way you are correct but `multitThreading` have huge topic since you have `synchronized` methods in your case (All Methods) you code its can be ran into [DeadLock](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2075692/java-concurrency/avoid-synchronization-deadlocks.html)

Comment: @Hosseini deadlocks should not be an issue in the given example as there is only one lock object the `MainActivity` class. Either a thread holds this lock object or not. However, if there are other classes that use synchronization as well with other lock objects, deadlocks are definitively an important thing to consider. As a rule of thumb one can say: If your code uses multiple different lock objects these objects **always** need to be acquired in the same order. Unfortunately it's not always that easy to ensure this rule...

Comment: we don't see any thing instead of `getter/setter` in here, we just say this is not way every time we need  protect `state` put it in `synchronized` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your change is correct so far. And as you already mentioned **every** access (local access as well) to these shared state variables must be using the synchronized accessors.

Furthermore, if the values of `LAT` and `LON` belong together (I assume you are representing a location with these values) you should make sure they can not be modified or retrieved independent of each other. That is you should not add a setter and getter for each value but one for both. And if these values belong together you could think of introducing a new class that represents both values like

```
public class Location {
    private double mLon;
    private double mLat;

    // Add getters and setters. These don't need to be synchronized
}
```

and change the synchronized accessors in `MainActivity` to

```
public static synchronized setLocation(final Location inLocation) {
    ...
}
```

Just for completeness using `synchronized` blocks is probably the most common but not the most efficient solution for implementing thread synchronization on shared state objects. If it comes to performance you should probably take a look at the classes in `java.util.concurrent`. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html) for a short introduction of the `Lock` object.

**UPDATE**:
Updated answer with code example

Answer (score 2):

First, `synchronized static methods` are type of Java's built-in locks. They use class object as a lock, so only one thread at a time can work with the class. If one thread executing one of the methods, other threads cannot execute any of the objects methods. This is locking type of synchronization. It affects performance. But if high performance is not required, this solution will work. You need mark methods that read/change data with `synchronized` keyword.

Second, I assume your variables mean coordinates of location: latitude and longitude. If so, they must be accessed together. You can make new composite class. If they are not accessed at the same time, it can lead to race condition.

PS: let us know if synchronization affects performance. There are non-locking at a class level solutions.